# Lync 2013 PSTN Gateways

Tags: lync, lync-2013

I am looking for a certified Lync 2013 to PSTN gateway chassis that can take different modules (ISDN PRI, ISDN BRI or Analog trunk modules).

I cant find any manufactures offering modularised gateways - does anyone know of manufacturers offering such gateways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should checkout the Lync Catalog at http://catalog.lync.com. Look under the Hardware /  Networking section. Many of the manufacturers allow you to mix and match PSTN interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend the AudioCodes Mediant devices.